# Not able to change the Light shade of iOS UINavigationBar in Xamarin Forms 4.5

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, uinavigationbar, ios13

I am trying to remove the light shade of Navigationbar in ios. Below is the code I tried. Also tried different scenarios, still the shade is not removed. I am using XF 4.5.0.356. Is there anything to do to get the exact color of my Navigationbar?

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0))
            {
                var appearance = new UINavigationBarAppearance();
                appearance.ConfigureWithTransparentBackground();
                appearance.LargeTitleTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes() { ForegroundColor = UIColor.White };
                appearance.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Orange;

                UINavigationBar.Appearance.CompactAppearance = appearance;
                UINavigationBar.Appearance.StandardAppearance = appearance;
                UINavigationBar.Appearance.ScrollEdgeAppearance = appearance;
                UINavigationBar.Appearance.Translucent = false;
            }
```

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0):

You should set the appearance to current `NavigationController.NavigationBar`:

```
    if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0))
    {
        var appearance = new UINavigationBarAppearance();
        appearance.ConfigureWithTransparentBackground();
        appearance.LargeTitleTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes() { ForegroundColor = UIColor.White };
        appearance.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Orange;

        this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.CompactAppearance = appearance;
        this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.StandardAppearance = appearance;
        this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.ScrollEdgeAppearance = appearance;
        this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.Translucent = false;

    }
```